# Enable VIM to CSS autocomplete for background-color: hsla and rgba

Tags: css, vim, autocomplete

I use VIM to edit CSS files. 
 offers language-specific keywords auto completion. For CSS background-color this list is offered:

```
transparent
rgb(
#
```

I mostly use hsla( and rgba(, how do I add these to the list?
Can I edit the css.vim file for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the default completion script:

   ```
   :e $VIMRUNTIME/autoload/csscomplete.vim
   ```
2. Save and edit a local copy:

   ```
   :saveas ~/.vim/autoload/csscomplete.vim
   ```
3. Search for `transparent`:

   ```
   /transp<CR>
   ```
4. Append the desired values:

   ```
   $i, "rgba(", "hsla("<Esc>
   ```
5. Repeat until you have edited all the relevant lines.
6. Write the file and quit:

   ```
   :x
   ```
7. Try it in a new session:

   ```
   $ vim foo.css
   ```

Comment: Thx, do you know any updated file, the default file is 9 years old, and is missing many css3 properties.